# Insert sys_guid generated value via jooq DSL

Tags: sql, oracle, dsl, jooq

I need help with jooq DSL. How can be written in jooq DSL insert like this one: `insert into t (c) values (sys_guid());` ?
For oracle.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you're missing a feature / support for a vendor-specific expression in jOOQ, plain SQL templating is your help:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating

In your case, write:

```java
DSL.using(configuration)
   .insertInto(T)
   .columns(T.C)
   .values(field("sys_guid()", T.C.getDataType()));
```